# Resolving wildcard FQDN - python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, networking, fqdn

I am trying to resolve FQDNs with a wildcard ex:(*.microsft.com) to update object-groups in network device that do not support wildcard FQDNs.

I have attempted to use

```
socket.gethostbyname_ex("\*.microsoft.com")
```

and

```
socket.gethostbyname_ex("*.microsoft.com")
```

but continue to get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

This wildcard is listed in Microsoft documentation, I have no reason to believe it is incorrect.

I have not been able to find documentation on this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no means to query a wildcard against DNS unless you have access to the entire table locally.